# how to handle missing json objects types when reading a JSON to a DF in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

how to handle missing JSON object types when reading a JSON to a DF in spark
to a case class

```
case class userInfo(user_id:String,name:String,div_id:String,div_Name:Option[String])
```

example json:

```
    {"user_id":"123ABC","name":"john","div_id":"Business"}
    {"user_id":"44wsxer","name":"Valenico"}
    {"user_id":"33qwe","name":"Jmayar"}
    {"user_id":"121ioi","name":"xyzz","div_id":"Support"}
```

how to read above json to DF and assign null for the div_Name object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps required:

- Make sure that fields that can be missing are declared as nullable  Scala types (either `Option[_]` or Java boxed types) in the class definition.

  In your case all fields are `String` so no additional changes are required.
- Make sure you provide a `schema` argument and not depend on schema inference. You can for example use `Encoder`:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

  val schema = Encoders.product[userInfo].schema

  spark.read.schema(schema).json(...)
  ```